# maximize dijit layout BorderContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo, maximize, dijit.layout

In this linked example there is a dijit layout of contentpanes.

[Example Link](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout.html)

Is there a way to  maximize the center pane to cover the whole layout.

I have tried using the following after giving the center panel and id  `id="center"`

```
dijit.ById("center").domNode.style.width='100%'
//and
dijit.ById("center").resize({w:1000,h:1000});
```

Comment: you have only the center or , you have other layout with it , also is the border container 100% width and height ?? can you explain more

Comment: In the link if you click on the first example there is top bottom trailing leading and center. I give id="center" to the center region. That's the one I'd like to expand to full screen. In my example version the center is around 500 pixels or 50% and is not 100 percent width to start. If I make it 100% width it doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Maybe [dojo/dom-style](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-style.html#set) would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize the center layout,knowing that you had set an id for this last , (`id="center"`) , you can use `dojo/dom-style` to set the a new widht and height for the pane layout,

in the bellow snippet I'managed to calculate parent width and height then apply the style to the center pane , also a preobleme here is when you resize the window all pane should get initial style , si all you have to do is excute resizing every window resize event ..

you can see the explained example bellow :

```js
require([ "dojo/on","dojo/dom-style", "dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"],function(On, domStyle,ready,registry,BorderContainer,ContentPane){
 ready(function(){
    // apply resize after 3 seconde
    window.setTimeout(resizeCenter,3000);
    On(window,"resize",function(e){
      console.log(e)
     resizeCenter();
    })
  })
  
  function resizeCenter(){
   var centerPane = registry.byId("center").domNode;
    parentWidth = domStyle.get(centerPane.parentNode,"width");
    parentWidth -=28;
    parentHeight = domStyle.get(centerPane.parentNode,"height");
    parentHeight -=28;
    ///why  removing 28 because  5*2 margin + 8*2 padding +2*1 borders = 28
    
    //set top left right bottom if all regions are set
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"top","5px");
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"bottom","5px");
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"left","5px");
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"right","5px");
    
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"z-index",10);
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"width",parentWidth+"px");
    domStyle.set(centerPane,"height",parentHeight+"px")
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
    dojoConfig= {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
    };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top pane</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" id="center">center</div>

      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'">Trailing pane</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The snippet seems to work perfectly. Dojo should add a feature like this to the layout to maximize and minimize any pane.

Comment: @techdog probably yes , bu t you can extend the js and create your own custumized contentepane that sweet your needs. (usinf define() )

Comment: This seems to work with center if it is a ContentPane but not if it is a BorderContainer or TabContainer which both give different behaviors.